# How do I prove that $\sum_{y=0}^{N-1}e^{2\pi i xy/N}=N\delta_{x,0}$?

Tags: mathematics, quantum-fourier-transform

I am trying to prove the following relation related to the Quantum Fourier Transform:

$$\sum_{y=0}^{N-1}e^{2\pi i\frac{x}{N}y} = \begin{cases}0 & \text{if } x\neq 0\mod N \\ N & \text{if } x=0\mod N\end{cases}.$$

I could not find the proof anywhere. What are the possible ways to proceed?

Comment: Try to draw the terms in the sum in the complex plane, it will be clear that they sum to $0$. For a proof see [this question on Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891875/proof-that-sum-of-complex-unit-roots-is-zero)

Answer (score 2):

The case of $x=0\text{ mod }N$ is straightforward - each term in the sum is $e^0=1$ and there are $N$ terms in the sum.

For $x\neq 0$, there are a number of ways you could do this. I tend to use the sum of a geometric progression:
$$
\sum_{r=0}^{N-1}a^r=\frac{a^N-1}{a-1},
$$
assuming $a\neq 1$. Hence, if we let $a=e^{2\pi ix/N}$, the sum is
$$
\frac{e^{2\pi ix}-1}{e^{2\pi ix/N}-1}=0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(y)=e^{2\pi i \frac{x}{N}y}, Y=\sum_{y=0}^{N-1}f(y)$. Clearly $f(0)=f(N)=1$.

If $x = 0\mod N$, then $f(y)=1$, hence $Y=N$.

If $x\not= 0 \mod N$, then $f(1)\not=1$.
Now $f(1)Y=\sum_{y=1}^{N}f(x) = Y - f(0) + f(N) = Y$, so $Y(f(1)-1)=0$. Since $f(1)\not=1$, then $Y=0$.